# Time not automatically changing

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angularjs to automatically change time in a simple html file by using an `ng-controller` but its only showing the initial time but not updating later

here is the `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Testing</title>

</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">

<div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <h1>{{data()}}</h1>
</div>
<script TYPE="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and the `main.js`

```
var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller("myctrl",function($scope)
{
$scope.data=function()
{
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    return n;
}
})
```

How do I make it update every time...?

Comment: You need to put the time update in a loop. Use Angular's $timeout to run a function every 1000 milliseconds: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout I found this jsFiddle demonstrating it: http://jsfiddle.net/otupman/fq4vg/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data()` only gets rand when the template is compiled. You need to use a timer to update the value. 
Something like this would work.

html template

```
<div ng-controller="timer" ng-app>
    {{time | date:'h:m:ss'}}
</div>
```

controller

```
function timer($scope, $interval){
    $scope.time = Date.now();
    $interval(function(){
       $scope.time = Date.now(); 
    },1000);
}
```

Also you can use `Date.now()` instead of `(new Date()).getTime()`

Answer (score 1):

You never update $scope.data,Angular wont do that for you.

```
var timeout;
var changeTime=function(){
    $scope.data = (new Date()).getTime();
    timeout = $timeout(changeTime,1000);
}
timeout= $timeout(changeTime,1000);
```

Comment: Seems easier to use `$interval`? (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval)

Comment: sure,but for some reason i usually use $timeout so i can control the interval between the timeouts

Answer (score 0):

You're only calling data once in this example. For it to update in real-time, you'll need the date called continuously like so:

```
var app=angular.module('myapp',[]);
app.controller("myctrl",function($scope, $timeout)
{

  // called every second
  var getTime = function(){
    $scope.data = (new Date()).getTime();
    $timeout(getTime, 1000, true);
  }

  getTime();
})
```

And in your view just get rid of the data() invocation and instead reference the model:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Testing</title>

</head>
<body ng-app="myapp">

<div ng-controller="myctrl">
    <h1>{{data}}</h1>
</div>
<script TYPE="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```